# Java 8 List<K> into Map<K, List<String>>

Tags: java

I have a list

```
List<MyObject> list;
```

And I want to convert this to a map of `Map<MyObject, List<String>>`

I tried

```
Map<MyObject, List<String>> map = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item, Collections.emptyList()));
```

But Java is not happy with the `item->item`:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exists so that List<T> conforms to Function<? super T, ? extends U>
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: @csmckelvey updated the question

Comment: You want `.collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item, item -> Collections.emptyList()));`; **both** arguments need to be `Function`s returning the relevant values.

Comment: Should the values be empty lists for all keys? Don't you want to fill those lists with some data? If yes, what would this data come from? Would by any chance the elements of each list correspond to an attribute of `MyObject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) expects a `Function` to convert the item to a value that will be placed in the map.  However, you have supplied `Collections.emptyList()`, which is not a `Function`.

It looks like you want an empty list for every item, so change

```
Collections.emptyList()
```

to

```
item -> Collections.emptyList()
```

However, [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) returns an *immutable* empty list, which is probably not what you want here.

> Returns an empty list (immutable). This list is serializable.

You may want

```
item -> new ArrayList<>()
```

Comment: @Kousha then you should accept it as answer, so that others can rely on it.

Comment: @TheGuest sorry, was waiting for the buffer time to run out!! Marked now

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified where the `String` elements of each `List<String>` come from.

If they come from each `MyObject` instance, you could try using [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) along with [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) instead of `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<MyObject, List<String>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            item -> item, 
            Collectors.mapping(item -> item.getSomeStringAttribute(),
                    Collectors.toList())));
```

If, instead of an attribute of `MyObject`, the elements of each list come from somewhere else, you can encapsulate the acquisition of each `String` element in a method:

```
Map<MyObject, List<String>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            item -> item, 
            Collectors.mapping(item -> someMethod(item),
                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Where `someMethod` would be as follows:

```
String someMethod(MyObject item) {
    // TODO get/calculate the String from the item
}
```

If, on the other side, you only want to initialize a map with empty lists as values for each `MyObject` instance, you don't need streams for that:

```
Map<MyObject, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(item -> map.put(item, new ArrayList<>()));
```